# Obtener los datos de un JsonResponse

Tags: php, laravel, json, laravel-5

Tengo un controlador que accede al método `searchUserByName` de otro controlador y devuelve un `JsonResponse`, esta variable `$user` entiendo que es un Json ¿No? ¿Si deseo obtener el valor del resutlado que hay dentro como debo hacerlo?

```
    /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function uploadSubmit(Request $request)
{

    foreach($request->file('file') as $file){
        try {
            ...
            ...
            $user = app('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
                ->searchUserByName($attributes['name']);

        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

    /**
 * @param $name
 * @return Response
 */
public function searchUserByName($name)
{

    try {
        $user = User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => ['Error'],
        ], 500);
    }


    return new JsonResponse([
        'data' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hay que hacer para que devuelva `$user` es `return $user`. Y `$user` es un objeto.

```
public function searchUserByName($name)
{

    try {
        $user = User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
        return $user;
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => ['Error'],
        ], 500);
    }
```

Pero ojo, tal y como lo tienes cualquier usuario que se llame "manolo" o "manuel" serán encontrados con la cadena de búsqueda "man" y entonces devolverá una `collection`. Para que encuentre un usuario con un texto exacto y solo devuelva un registro debería quedar así:

```
public function searchUserByName($name)
    {

        try {
            $user = User::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
            return $user;
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => ['Error'],
            ], 500);
        }
```

En el caso de querer devolver un jSon la salida sería la siguiente:

```
return $user->toJson();
```

Comment: Gracias , la respuesta es válida pero si prefiero devolver un Json? Desde donde lo llamaré quiero un objeto... pero la idea de devolver un Json , es porque si hay un error devuelvo un error

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias , muy amable